# Hint in integration $\int\frac{x^{2}}{\left(x\cos x-\sin x \right )\left( x\sin x+\cos x \right )}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In the following integration

$$\int \frac{x^{2}}{\left ( x\cos x-\sin x \right )\left ( x\sin x+\cos x \right )}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried alot. But does not get any proper start.

Can anybody provide me a hint.

Comment: we had this question more the once here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe the following trick
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(x \cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}&=\frac{x\cos x(x \cos x-\sin x)+x\sin x(x\sin x+\cos x)}{(x \cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}
\\\\&=\frac{x\cos x}{x\sin x+\cos x}+\frac{x \sin x}{x \cos x-\sin x}
\\\\&=\frac{(x\sin x+\cos x)'}{(x\sin x+\cos x)}-\frac{(x \cos x-\sin x)'}{(x \cos x-\sin x)}
\end{align}
$$ then one may conclude.

Answer (score 6):

Notice
$$x^{2}=x^2\left ( \sin^2x+\cos^2x \right )$$
then
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{x^{2}}{\left ( x\cos x-\sin x \right )\left ( x\sin x+\cos x \right )}\, \mathrm{d}x&=\int \frac{x^2\left ( \sin^2x+\cos^2x \right )}{\left ( x\cos x-\sin x \right )\left ( x\sin x+\cos x \right )}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int \frac{x\cos x}{x\sin x+\cos x}\, \mathrm{d}x+\int \frac{x\sin x}{x\cos x-\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\ln\left | x\sin x+\cos x \right |-\ln\left | x\cos x-\sin x \right |+C
\end{align*}